# Using DocumentClient.ReadDocumentAsync when you do not know the partitionkey

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-3.1

I have a situation where I need to retrieve a particular document but I do not know it's PartitionKey.

The method looks like this:

```
    public async Task<T> GetItemAsyncNoGroupId(string id)
    {
        try
        {
            Document document = await client.ReadDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId, id),
                new RequestOptions() { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(Undefined.Value) });

            return (T)(dynamic)document;
        }
        catch (DocumentClientException e)
        {
            if (e.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

I passed in the Undefined.Value to the PartitionKey object and that didn't work.  I also didn't pass any PartionKey object into the ReadDocumentAsync method and that didn't work.  I always get 'No Content' passed back.  Any suggestions on how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a cross partition query. Read about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.feedoptions.enablecrosspartitionquery?view=azure-dotnet).

Comment: Hmm I have tried this and I still haven't been able to get it to work.  I the list that is returned is empty.  I know the item is there if I manually put the PartionKey in it I can get the item I am looking for.